# Socket.IO: 400 Bad Request

Tags: socket.io

I'm trying to make a connection to a node server from a page served by an APACHE server but I'm running into issues with the connection. I was getting cross domain errors until I set origin to allow all but now I'm getting a 400 bad request error.

server

```
  var http = require('http');
   var io = require('socket.io');

   var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
       console.log('Connection');
       response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
       //response.write('hello world');
       response.end();
   });

   server.listen(8001);
    
    io.listen(server);
    
    var socket = io.listen(server);
    socket.set('origins', '*');
    socket.on('connection', function() {
        console.log('mooo');
    });
```

client

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>
<script src = "http://localhost:8001"> </script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8001');
        
</script>
```

error:

```
GET XHR http://localhost:8001/socket.io/ [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 2ms]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running fine without the following code but Im not running on apache. I have got the output "hello world" in browser (http://localhost:8001/).

```
var socket = io.listen(server);
io.set('origins', '*');
io.on('connection', function() {
    console.log('mooo');
});
```

How are your accessing the page because 404 is something that your page can not be located by the request.

Comment: I am access the page through a page served by APACHE. APACHE -> Client -> Node. Via this line in the javascript <script src ="http://localhost:8001> </script>. The error is appearing inside the browser console, not the node console. The node server shouldn't be serving anything to the browser, just opening a socket.